# Simon Holmedal style with Geometry nodes

Tags: node-editor, geometry

Big fan of Simon Holmedal work. Wonder how can we do similar stuff as shown in the reference picture using geometry nodes? Please help to give some tips and tricks on how should I start it.

[image]

The image is from his work "The Game Awards" You can look it up on youtube. It is insanely good.

Comment: Hello ! Honestly the base geometry doesn't look that complicated, the bulk of the work is setting up a good material and a good lighting environment here. What have you tried and where are you stuck exactly ?

Comment: Hello, Chien ,, I like the piece, too .. but it must combine half-a-dozen little techniques. (As Gorgious says, not just in the model) To make questions that are answerable on BSE, really, you would have to ask about one of them at a time. The best way to do that would be to make some progress on your own, say, to the basic geometry to begin with,  ask about that, and so on with subsequent steps, if you don't feel they're going where you want them to.

Comment: Hello Gorgious and Robin, thanks for the response. First of all, I must say that I'm a newbie to geometry node and I don't think this is an easy piece to build in geometry node by all means. I've followed a few tutorials on YouTube to get the idea on how to use geometry node to scatter stuff and all. But that gets me nowhere close to this. I probably need someone to break this down for me and let me know which few nodes I should explore to achieve this. Appreciate if anyone could help.